# I cannot do any changes or save them in my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I cannot do any changes in my wordpress site after I uploaded it on my server. I was able to do it earlier but can't do it now.

Can anybody suggest anything?

- Should I add a htaccess file?
- Is it about the permissions thing?

If I go to save the changes it gives me an error;

> "There was a problem with your action please try again or reload the
>   page"

Comment: Do you get any extra feedback in your browser console? (ctrl+shift+k in Firefox, ctr+shift+j in Chrome)

Comment: Try to give some time to the browser to load the website. Also provide the .htaccess file content

Comment: Did you run the search-replace plugin? It changes the url of  your local site to your actual host.

Comment: I think its in your folder permission, login to your ftp and try to check permission of the folder of wp-content, try to put to 0755